# master reset on phone

Tags: iphone

I had a iPhone that was in my ex boyfriend's name he took it from me before I could erase any of my contents out of it.

I asked him to do it and he won't. Now he is calling people I had saved on the phone.

Can I do a master reset on the phone without having the phone so he will stop harassing people that is stored in the phone?

I have tried to contact the Verizon store but they said nothing can be done.

Comment: Should this be protected? This could be a spam seed

Comment: @Unicorns It's had no deleted posts so far and there's no point protecting questions without at least one example of a poor post resulting from it, especially as protecting it decreases the availability for new users to provide good answers.

Answer (score 3):

If it is still signed into your Apple ID and has Find My Phone enabled, erase it via iCloud: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2701

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a sticky situation...

You might be able to wipe the phone if your phone had Find My iPhone enabled in iCloud.

You'll need to go to http://icloud.com and login, then select Find My iPhone and from there see if your iPhone is listed.

Here you can lock the phone to prevent him using it, or Erase everything on it.

If you didn't do this there is nothing more you can do other than contact the police about his behaviour.

Comment: no when i get on icloud an then find my phone it says all devices are off line i called apple they said that means he has the phone off but when i call it, it still rings

Comment: The SIM card may be in a different phone... You can still press the button to erase or lock the phone, but if he has written or otherwise copied the numbers then your out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

And you won't ever be able to access your old phone? Because if so, you could just go into the phone settings > General > Reset > Reset all content and settings

If not, and he won't talk to you, talk to some of his friends about it. Have them convince him he is being extremely rude.

This is bullying, and needs to be stopped.